# Keras Tensor Shaping Problems (slicing) add_loss zero suppression loss

Tags: keras, shapes, tensor, loss-function, loss

I implemented an autoencoder which takes as an input real images, the latent space should be an black and white encoding of the states of this image. (it's a boardgame)
I'm trying to create a new loss using the Layer class.
I want to implement the zero suppression loss.
My problem is in the line, where the slicing happens. (line 7 here)
Can anyone help me to solve the slicing problem

```
class Zero_Suppress(Layer):
    def __init__(self, rate=1e-2):
        super(Zero_Suppress, self).__init__()
        self.rate = rate

    def call(self, inputs):
        loss = K.mean(inputs, axis = [0,1])
        loss = K.mean(loss[:, 1:], axis =1)
        #loss = K.reshape(loss, (-1,1,1))
        self.add_loss(loss * self.rate)
        return inputs
```

The error code I receive:

````
ValueError: in user code:

    min_paper.py:17 call  *
        loss = K.mean(loss[:, 1:], axis =1)
    ValueError: Index out of range using input dim 0; input has only 0 dims for '{{node zero__suppress/strided_slice}} = StridedSlice[Index=DT_INT32, T=DT_FLOAT, begin_mask=1, ellipsis_mask=0, end_mask=3, new_axis_mask=0, shrink_axis_mask=0](zero__suppress/Mean, zero__suppress/strided_slice/stack, zero__suppress/strided_slice/stack_1, zero__suppress/strided_slice/stack_2)' with input shapes: [], [2], [2], [2] and with computed input tensors: input[3] = <1 1>.```
````